# std::map insert doesn't compile due to "cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair<MyKey, MyValue>' to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &&'"

Tags: c++, build, compilation, initializer

I'm trying to create an std::map for `<MyKey, MyValue>`. `MyKey` is an enum, `MyValue` an external class.

Calling `myMap.insert({ key, value })` always fails the compile with error

```
"cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair<MyKey, MyValue>' to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &&'"
```

Although primitive data types always work with `std::map.insert()`, this problem happens so often when trying to contain classes written by someone else. With different third-party classes, I've tried many workarounds such as constructing objects beforehand or setting their attributes after insertion. But I've yet to find a systematic way to fix this. It seems `std::map` is much harder to get right than, say, python's `dict`.

Example: with the thirdparty lib `cppzmq`, Visual Studio 2017

```
enum MyKey {
    key1,
    key2
}

std::map<MyKey, zmq::socket_t> mymap;

std::shared_ptr<zmq::context_t> g_context = std::make_shared<zmq::context_t>(1);

zmq:socket_t sock(*g_context, zmq::socket_type::pair);

mymap.insert({ key1, sock });
```

gives me the above error.

What does this error mean and how to fix it in general?

Comment: It's hard to formulate a cogent answer without a [mcve].

Comment: @RSahu I'm trying to do so and updated my question.

Comment: My guess is that `zmq::socket_t` is not copyable

Comment: Yep, [`zmq::socket_t` is not copyable](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/de05d330294542526180260de0ab9cb5b6846df5/zmq.hpp#L1586)

Comment: [`zmq::socket_t` is movable](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/de05d330294542526180260de0ab9cb5b6846df5/zmq.hpp#L1544) so you could try moving instead of copying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert a move-only object into a `std::map` then your only option is to move it into map. Adapting your example, you could try this:

```
mymap.insert({key1, zmq:socket_t{*g_context, zmq::socket_type::pair}});
```

You could also do this:

```
zmq:socket_t sock{*g_context, zmq::socket_type::pair};
mymap.insert({key1, std::move(sock)});
// note that sock is in a "moved from" state after this point
```

I see that you're coming from Python and might not be familiar with move semantics so the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm pretty new to C++11 indeed.

Comment: Btw, the current compiler error messages are as cryptic as pre-C++11 days, is there a knowledge base for working through these errors?

Comment: @kakyo I guess there's old stackoverflow questions. If you want better error messages, use a fresh new C++17 compiler.

Comment: @kakyo Though even that doesn't really help that much. Understanding the cryptic error messages comes with experience. C++ is a complicated language so the error messages are always going to complicated.